# Add changing data to the description of entity

Tags: cesiumjs

I have created an entity, initialized its position with an array of lat/long. That's to say, the position of an entity is changed with time.

Now, I would like to add the current position to the description of an entity, which is shown when the entity is selected.

How to do that?